# Visual Studio Code не работает F2

Tags: visual-studio-code

Клацаю мышкой на переменную, нажимаю <kbd>F2</kbd>, появляется поле, пишу новое название переменной, нажимаю <kbd>Enter</kbd>. В итоге название переменной не меняется. До переустановки винды все работало, а сейчас нет, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Fn кнопка есть? Какая ОС?

Comment: о, спасибо ! я не знал что так можно

Comment: Для того, что бы эта функция работала, для используемого языка должен быть доступен language server. Если его нет, то и работать не будет

Answer (score 1):

Установил в VS Code "Unity Code Snippets"  и все заработало.
[Unity Code Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cemuka.unity-code-snippets)